# maven compiler plugin conflict

Tags: maven, compiler-construction

I use maven compiler plugin version 2.3.2 and I updated third party package and since then when I execute `mvn clean install` I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project adserver: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>   [ERROR] \amobee\svn\afs-wurfl\adserver-parent\adserver\src\main\java\com\amobee\datamodel\mediation\Publisher.java:[8,42] package edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util does not
>   exist
>   Blockquote

I looked at the pom of the third party package and I saw that they moved from version 2.3 of this plugin to 2.0.2.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the messages "Publisher.java:[8,42] package edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util does not exist" it looks more like missing a dependency than a plugin problem.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't explain it correctly. The missing dependency was never part of my pom, when I use the old version of the third party package then the code compiles.

Comment: May be you didn't clean up the import statements etc. Can you show the pom file?

Comment: I can't upload the pom file it's to long, is there any way to attach it?. the package I replaced is wurfl from 1.2 to 1.4.3.1.

Comment: Pastbin ? Or gist on github ?